# ag-grid cellRendering with deltaRowDataMode

Tags: updates, ag-grid, cellrenderer

Hi I have some cells with custom rendering
when I update the all data, the [deltaRowDataMode](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#delta-row-data) does not hnadle the change of my cutsom cell rendering. Other cells of the updated row are correctly updated.

How can I give a clue to ag grid to compare correctly this custom cell

Comment: Please share a snippet more clearance

Answer (score 4):

I have just had the same issue and found a clue from the ag-grid documentation. In the [Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#component-refresh) help doc it talks about the `ICellRendererComp.refresh` method:

> ```js
> // Mandatory - Get the cell to refresh. Return true if the refresh succeeded, otherwise return false.
> // If you return false, the grid will remove the component from the DOM and create
> // a new component in it's place with the new values.
> refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean;
> ```

and in the example further down:

> ```js
> // gets called whenever the user gets the cell to refresh
> MyCellRenderer.prototype.refresh = function(params) {
>     // set value into cell again
>     this.eValue.innerHTML = params.valueFormatted ? params.valueFormatted : params.value;
>     // return true to tell the grid we refreshed successfully
>     return true;
> };
> ```

I then implemented a refresh function on my `CellRenderer` as below without changing any of the cell contents:

```js
statusCellRenderer.prototype.refresh = function (params) {
    //ensure the status cell\directive refreshes when the grid data is refreshed using deltaRowDataMode
    this.params = params;
    return true;
};
```

So in my case, I am refreshing the `rowData` of the grid on a polling cycling and I didn't want the grid to keep losing the selected row. I set the `deltaRowDataMode` and `getRowNodeId` properties on the `gridOptions` and then implemented the refresh function to make the cell re-render on a refresh. The refresh also re-renders a directive in my cell.

Comment: This worked well for me. In my case I was trying to toggle a row to be a full width cell renderer via the isFullWidthCell callback in GridOptions. I found that using the usual `gridAPI.refreshCells()` did not initialize a full width cell renderer, and instead I used `gridAPI.redrawRows()` to initialize and tear down the full width cell renderer. See [Redraw Rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/view-refresh/#redraw-rows)